# How do I run modals windows from code with cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, modal-dialog

I`m trying to run a window as modal directly from the code.
My program starts and a main NSWindows is showed.A thread still running to see if the user has a valid distribution. if he doesn't I need to run a modal.I mean, I have no buttons clicked in the interface.I've designed a NSWindow on the interface builder for a password set, and I want to call it only when my validation is not successful.
I have tested and realized that these methods which are responsible for modal windows running only work in a IBAction environment.

```
//This doesn't work
-(void) showPasswordWindow
{
        [NSApp runModalForWindow:[self window]];

}

//this works But its not useful for me =(
- (IBAction) passwordWindowButton:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:[self window]];
}
```

Please, help this newbie =)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check: are you calling the method on the main thread?

to check, add this to `showPasswordWindow`

```
NSLog(@"Main thread? %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
```

Comment: Yes.The validation begins in this method:
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification*) aNotification

Comment: Leandro: I believe cobbal means “are you calling `runModalForWindow:` on the main thread?”. Where you start your secondary thread from doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, guys.Now I got it.Thanks for the help! =)

the answer I got is 
"Main thread? 1"